# How to use AWS for free hosting of a web app (Docker, Nginx, Angular, Django)?

Tags: django, angular, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

I am a total beginner and just completed the first version of my web application.

I am using Docker, Nginx, Angular & Django. Note that the backend works on static files and uses a simple database for User Registration.

I want to deploy it to a free, cloud solution. I heard that I can use AWS Elastic Beanstalk but found a bit complicated both the configuration and the pricing policy.

**Question**
Can anybody guide me through what to consider or even better, what selection  I have to make in order to host my web app on AWS without a charge?

PS: I don't know If I have to mention this, but in case the web app attracts a satisfying number of users, I would adjust the implementation in order the user to be able to upload and use my services upon their own data (and not upon the csv files). In this case, I might have to use other AWS services or migrate to another cloud solution. Just to say that both of them are welcome!

Comment: You can see what's in the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/).  I feel like it's very limited, and the core services like EC2 limit you to the very smallest instance sizes and "free" runs out after a year.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily host an Angular app on AWS within the free tier (1 year) limits. I have hosted a handful of Angular apps so far using AWS S3 + AWS Cloudfront.

**AWS S3** is used to *host* your static files. You first do a `ng serve --prod` where the Angular compiler will generate a `/dist` folder (in your project directory) containing *all* the static files (i.e. js, images, fonts, etc) required to run your angular app. Then you upload all your static files onto a AWS S3 bucket.

**AWS Cloudfront** is a cloud *caching* service. As the word "cache" suggests, it caches your static files. By setting up a Cloudfront cache in-front of your S3 bucket, it allows you to bypass the monthly 20,000 GET requests limited for free tier - because users' HTTP requests will be served from the Cloudfront cache instead of, directly from your S3 bucket. Cloudfront free tier gives you 2 million HTTP(S) requests per month.

The good thing about hosting on AWS S3 instead of an EC2 instance (P.S. Elastic beanstalk also creates EC2 instance) is that you can have multiple S3 buckets and Cloudfront distributions in 1 free tier account. As long as you stay within the limits, S3: 2,000 PUT Requests, 20,000 GET request; Cloudfront: 2million HTTPS requests. You can end up hosting several apps with one AWS free tier account. But if you're using EC2, you're almost limited to only 1 instance (because 31days x 24 hours = 744hrs which is 6 hours shy of the 750 hours limit). Unless you set up for your EC2 instances to turn on and off.

There are plenty of guides demonstrating how to do this, here are some of them:

1. [Deploy an Angular with S3 and CloudFront](https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/here-is-how-easy-it-is-to-deploy-an-angular-spa-single-page-app-as-a-static-website-using-s3-and-6aa446db38ef)
2. [Use S3 and CloudFront to host Static Single Page Apps (SPAs) with HTTPs and www-redirects](https://gist.github.com/bradwestfall/b5b0e450015dbc9b4e56e5f398df48ff)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, what about my database? Did you consider this in your suggested solution (Cloudfront and S3) ?

Comment: Ah, my bad. You can host a database instance on AWS using AWS RDS. For your Django API server, you can host it on an AWS EC2 - with docker, you can easily deploy on an EC2 linux instance. Here's a guide [Django-Nginx-Docker Production Setup with AWS](https://medium.com/@niharmishra511/django-nginx-docker-production-setup-with-aws-aeeed111e3fb). Sorry, I have never hosted a Django app because my colleague (backend) did it... Hope this at least points you in the right direction and helps you identify which cloud service you need b/c there are so so many different services to use...

Comment: Nice. So, the "right" free solution is EC2 (all except database) along with RDS (only database). Can I use both for free under the limitations of "750 hours per month" and "20 GB storage", respectively?

Comment: Yup, definitely, RDS is a separate cloud service from EC2 so they don't count together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to deploy to a linux machine, Elastic Beanstalk is not useful for your use case (it's for automated scaling). I would do the following:

- AWS S3 to deploy your angular app using Static Website hosting (one possible tutorial is this https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/here-is-how-easy-it-is-to-deploy-an-angular-spa-single-page-app-as-a-static-website-using-s3-and-6aa446db38ef
- Amazon ECS( Container service) is used to deploy your containers. [This will help with that step](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/).

OR

- Simple Amazon EC2 (its a linux server) with the [entire environment set up with docker](https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/deploying-on-aws-free-tire-with-docker-and-fabric-d9eca7c629e6).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, my database goes either to ECS or to EC2?

Comment: Ideally i would put it on RDS (Available in free tier). EC2 is just a server(for example install Ubuntu). ECS is for containers like docker.

Comment: Nice, so what about that? I could probably deploy my 2 containers on EC2, the 1st one is Nginx serving Angular static files, while the 2nd one is the Django app. Also, I will use RDS for my database and of course connect it with EC2. Is it right? Are there alternatives?

Comment: It's correct but you can use S3 for serving Angiular Static files. This means you get the benefits of S3 which is quite good for serving static files, plus easily add ssl using cloudfront, unless you have a specific need to use a NGINX container.